# Ignore CSS out of div

Tags: html, css

I try to fill a *div* with templates to preview them. The templates come from a database and are set with php.
My Problem: Some of the entries are whole Websites (with *head* and css).

**Question:** Is it possible to ignore the css information - that are set inside the div - outside of it? It musn't be a *div* that'll be filled.

Example:

```
page...
<div>
   $template
</div>
... page
```

inside the template there are whole website templates as html, so the css information of the templates destroy the index sites css.

I hope it's more clearly now.

Comment: please clearly define the problem

Comment: How do you get the content? ajax?

Comment: sounds like a propper usecase for an `<iframe>`

Comment: All the templates are loaded and hidden. OnButton jscript will show another template.

Comment: Can't you remove this `<head>` information "before" you upload it to the database?

Comment: the templates aren't provided by me. so: No, I can't...

Comment: But: Is it a good idea to remove from the templates everything but the body with php?

Comment: Have you tried including the template within an [`iframe`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I had once the requirement of getting a full html page on a variable, and retrieving only the `body` content of it... It may suit your case here.

Let's assume we have a variable called `$page_content` with the whole html markup, including `<head>` and all. We would need to do something like this:

```
<?php
    $page_content; //Full page's content

    $split = explode("<body>", $page_content); //Split content on body's open tag
    $body_content = $split[1]; //Get content only after body's open tag
    $body_content = explode("</body>", $body_content)[0]; //Get content until body's close tag

    echo $body_content;
?>
```

Of course, you would need to be sure to have the **well formed** `<body>` and `</body>` tags...